# pass array by reference

Tags: c, arrays

I cant figure out where I am messing up. I am passing an array of character pointers. Inside the function I am trying to use strtok to break up a string into smaller pieces to be assigned to the `char *` array. I can try printing it off in the function and it all shows up correctly. As soon as I try to print it back in main I just get garbage.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define CMDLEN 100
#define MAXARG 5
void prompt();
int getCommand (char* cmdAndParameters[]);

int main() {
     int numArgs = 0;
     char* cmdAndParameters [MAXARG];

     while (true){
          prompt ();
          numArgs = getCommand (cmdAndParameters);
     }
}

void prompt() {
     printf("shell> ");
}

int getCommand(char* cmdAndParameters[]){
     int argNum = 0;
     bool foundArg = true;
     char* delimiters = " \t\n";
     char userRequest[CMDLEN];

     fgets(userRequest,sizeof(userRequest), stdin); 

     if ((cmdAndParameters[argNum] = strtok(userRequest, delimiters)) != NULL)
     {  
          argNum++;

          for (; argNum < MAXARG && foundArg; argNum++) {
               if ((cmdAndParameters[argNum] = strtok(NULL,delimiters))
                         == NULL) 
               {
                    foundArg = false;
               }
               // merely to test output remove later
               else {printf("%s\n", cmdAndParameters[argNum]);}
          } 

     }

     return argNum;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, your inner array of chars is allocated "automatic", which is to say, on the stack.  When you do the strtok, you're assigning a pointer to memory allocated on the stack, and then returning -- which means the memory is no longer allocated.

Move the userRequest array into file scope (ie, outside a block) or make the allocation 'static' and you'll have a better shot.

**Update**

Well, it's a little more than that, now that I look again.

First of all, you can clean it up considerably if you use a while loop, something like

```
argNum = 0;
while((cmdAndParameters[argNum++] = strtok(userRequest, delimiters)) != NULL)
    ;  /* all the work is happening in the conditional part of the while */
```

or even a for loop as

```
for(argNum = 0; 
    (cmdAndParameters[argNum] = strtok(userRequest, delimiters)) != NULL);
    argNum++)
    ; /* still all the work is in the for */
```

and now if `argNum > 0` you know you found something.

Second, you need to think about how and when you're allocating memory.  Your `cmdAndParameters` array is allocated when `main` starts (on the stack, it's "automatic") so it's around as long as your program, you're okay there.  But your `userRequest` array is allocated auto in `getCommand`; when `getCommand` returns, the memory is deallocated; the stack pointer moves back over it and you have no guarantees any longer.  So when you do the `strtok`, you're saving pointers into stack, which can lead to no good.

Comment: Your `for()` version is buggy, it increments `argNum` twice each time around the loop.

Comment: Adding to @caf's comment, it's probably important to note that the first parameter to strtok needs to be NULL on each iteration but the first, or you'll get an infinite loop. As such a `userRequest = NULL;` needs adding too.

Comment: @caf Damn cut&paste. Corrected. @Mac, this looked a lot like homework, I didn't want to give a full solution.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want

```
for (; argNum < MAXARG && foundArg; argNum++)
```

or something like

```
for(argCntr = argNum; argCntr < MAXARG && foundArg; argCntr++)
```

Hope that helps.